# Eclipse open a new web browser tab on every build

Tags: eclipse, browser

I'm using Eclipse Juno (Java EE) + Tomcat and everything works fine but one thing is annoying. Every time when I press the run button, Eclipse opens a new web browser tab (I use chrome as external web browser). Is it possible to tell Eclipse that it should refresh the tab instead of open a new one?

Thanks and best regards

konze

Comment: Which page opens in Chrome?

Comment: Chrome opens the current file I'm working on